# Integer List does not load correct integer

Tags: java, android

I am new here so sorry if i make mistakes. I am also from germany so sorry for the bad english.

I have two problems with my code. 
The first one is that the Integer List "my" gets everytime the same Integer and the second problem is that the for loop does not work when i pressed the start button a second time. 
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
String text;
MediaPlayer mp;
int i;
List<Integer> my=new ArrayList<Integer>();;
int load;
int an=0;
String[] help;
boolean existing=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText ed=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            text=ed.getText().toString();
            tts();
        }
    });
    Button lös=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    lös.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText ed=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            ed.setText("");
        }
    });
}
public void tts(){
    if (text.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Gib erstmal was zum aussprechen ein!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        text = text.replace("A", "a");
        text = text.replace("B", "b");
        text = text.replace("C", "c");
        text = text.replace("D", "d");
        text = text.replace("E", "e");
        text = text.replace("F", "f");
        text = text.replace("G", "g");
        text = text.replace("H", "h");
        text = text.replace("I", "i");
        text = text.replace("J", "j");
        text = text.replace("K", "k");
        text = text.replace("L", "l");
        text = text.replace("M", "m");
        text = text.replace("N", "n");
        text = text.replace("O", "o");
        text = text.replace("P", "p");
        text = text.replace("Q", "q");
        text = text.replace("R", "r");
        text = text.replace("S", "s");
        text = text.replace("T", "t");
        text = text.replace("U", "u");
        text = text.replace("V", "v");
        text = text.replace("W", "w");
        text = text.replace("X", "x");
        text = text.replace("Y", "y");
        text = text.replace("Z", "z");
        text = text.replace("Ä", "ä");
        text = text.replace("Ö", "ö");
        text = text.replace("Ü", "ü");



        if (text.contains("cks")) {
            text = text.replace("cks", "40,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ieh")) {
            text = text.replace("ieh", "8,");
        }
        if (text.contains("sch")){
            text = text.replace("sch", "27,");
        }
        if (text.contains("chs")){
            text = text.replace("chs", "40,");
        }

        if (text.contains("ie")) {
            text = text.replace("ie", "1,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ih")) {
            text = text.replace("ih", "8,");
        }
        if (text.contains("üh")) {
            text = text.replace("üh", "9,");
        }
        if (text.contains("uh")) {
            text = text.replace("uh", "10,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ee")) {
            text = text.replace("ee", "11,");
        }
        if (text.contains("eh")){
            text = text.replace("eh", "11,");
        }
        if (text.contains("öh")){
            text = text.replace("öh", "12,");
        }
        if (text.contains("oh")){
            text = text.replace("oh", "13,");
        }
        if (text.contains("oo")){
            text = text.replace("oo", "13,");
        }
        if (text.contains("äh")){
            text = text.replace("äh", "14,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ah")){
            text = text.replace("ah", "15,");
        }
        if (text.contains("aa")){
            text = text.replace("aa", "15,");
        }
        if (text.contains("eu")){
            text = text.replace("eu", "16,");
        }
        if (text.contains("äu")){
            text = text.replace("äu", "16,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ei")){
            text = text.replace("ei", "17,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ai")){
            text = text.replace("ai", "17,");
        }
        if (text.contains("au")){
            text = text.replace("au", "18,");
        }
        if (text.contains("pp")){
            text = text.replace("pp", "19,");
        }
        if (text.contains("tt")){
            text = text.replace("tt", "20,");
        }
        if (text.contains("dt")){
            text = text.replace("dt", "20,");
        }
        if (text.contains("th")){
            text = text.replace("th", "20,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ck")){
            text = text.replace("ck", "21,");
        }
        if (text.contains("bb")){
            text = text.replace("bb", "22,");
        }
        if (text.contains("dd")){
            text = text.replace("dd", "23,");
        }
        if (text.contains("gg")){
            text = text.replace("gg", "24,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ff")){
            text = text.replace("ff", "25,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ph")){
            text = text.replace("ph", "25,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ss")){
            text = text.replace("ss", "26,");
        }
        if (text.contains("rr")){
            text = text.replace("rr", "30,");
        }
        if (text.contains("rh")){
            text = text.replace("rh", "30,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ll")){
            text = text.replace("ll", "35,");
        }
        if (text.contains("mm")){
            text = text.replace("mm", "36,");
        }
        if (text.contains("nn")){
            text = text.replace("nn", "37,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ng")){
            text = text.replace("ng", "37,");
        }
        if (text.contains("pf")){
            text = text.replace("pf", "39,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ks")){
            text = text.replace("ks", "40,");
        }
        if (text.contains("gs")){
            text = text.replace("gs", "40,");
        }
        if (text.contains("tz")){
            text = text.replace("tz", "41,");
        }

        if (text.contains("t")){
            text = text.replace("t", "20,");
        }
        if (text.contains("p")){
            text = text.replace("p", "19,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ä")){
            text = text.replace("ä", "14,");
        }
        if (text.contains("c")){
            text = text.replace("c", "21,");
        }
        if (text.contains("b")){
            text = text.replace("b", "22,");
        }
        if (text.contains("k")){
            text = text.replace("k", "21,");
        }
        if (text.contains("d")){
            text = text.replace("d", "23,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ü")){
            text = text.replace("ü", "2,");
        }
        if (text.contains("y")){
            text = text.replace("y", "2,");
        }
        if (text.contains("u")){
            text = text.replace("u", "3,");
        }
        if (text.contains("e")){
            text = text.replace("e", "4,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ä")){
            text = text.replace("ä", "4,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ö")){
            text = text.replace("ö", "5,");
        }
        if (text.contains("o")){
            text = text.replace("o", "6,");
        }
        if (text.contains("a")){
            text = text.replace("a", "7,");
        }
        if (text.contains("g")){
            text = text.replace("g", "24,");
        }
        if (text.contains("s")){
            text = text.replace("s", "26,");
        }
        if (text.contains("f")){
            text = text.replace("f", "25,");
        }
        if (text.contains("v")){
            text = text.replace("v", "25,");
        }
        if (text.contains("ß")){
            text = text.replace("ß", "26,");
        }
        if (text.contains("r")){
            text = text.replace("r", "30,");
        }
        if (text.contains("h")){
            text = text.replace("h", "31,");
        }
        if (text.contains("w")){
            text = text.replace("w", "32,");
        }
        if (text.contains("j")){
            text = text.replace("j", "34,");
        }
        if (text.contains("l")){
            text = text.replace("l", "35,");
        }
        if (text.contains("m")){
            text = text.replace("m", "36,");
        }
        if (text.contains("n")){
            text = text.replace("n", "37,");
        }
        if (text.contains("x")){
            text = text.replace("x", "40,");
        }
        if (text.contains("z")){
            text = text.replace("z", "41,");
        }
        if (text.contains("i")){
            text = text.replace("i", "1,");
        }
        //if (text.contains("q"))text = text.replace("q","42,");  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        //if (text.contains(" "))text=text.replace(" ","wait");
            text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1); //
            help = text.split(",");

            for (int in = 0; in < help.length; in++) {
                if (help[i].equals("40")) {
                    an = R.raw.a40;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("27")) {
                    an = R.raw.a27;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("1")) {
                    an = R.raw.a1;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("9")) {
                    an = R.raw.a9;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("10")) {
                    an = R.raw.a10;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("11")) {
                    an = R.raw.a11;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("12")) {
                    an = R.raw.a12;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("13")) {
                    an = R.raw.a13;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("14")) {
                    an = R.raw.a14;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("15")) {
                    an = R.raw.a15;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("16")) {
                    an = R.raw.a16;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("17")) {
                    an = R.raw.a17;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("18")) {
                    an = R.raw.a18;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("19")) {
                    an = R.raw.a19;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("20")) {
                    an = R.raw.a20;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("21")) {
                    an = R.raw.a21;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("22")) {
                    an = R.raw.a22;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("23")) {
                    an = R.raw.a23;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("24")) {
                    an = R.raw.a24;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("25")) {
                    an = R.raw.a25;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("26")) {
                    an = R.raw.a26;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("30")) {
                    an = R.raw.a30;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("35")) {
                    an = R.raw.a35;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("36")) {
                    an = R.raw.a36;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("37")) {
                    an = R.raw.a37;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("39")) {
                    an = R.raw.a39;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("40")) {
                    an = R.raw.a40;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("41")) {
                    an = R.raw.a41;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("2")) {
                    an = R.raw.a2;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("3")) {
                    an = R.raw.a3;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("4")) {
                    an = R.raw.a4;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("5")) {
                    an = R.raw.a5;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("6")) {
                    an = R.raw.a6;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("31")) {
                    an = R.raw.a31;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("32")) {
                    an = R.raw.a32;
                    my.add(an);
                }
                if (help[i].equals("34")) {
                    an = R.raw.a34;
                    my.add(an);
                }
        }
            i = 0;
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, my.get(i));
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mp.start();
            existing = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    i++;
    try {
        load=my.get(i);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        load= 0;
    }
    if (load==0){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Fertig",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mp.release();
    }
    else {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, load);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp.start();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem 1

you have

```
i = 0;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, my.get(i));
```

So it will always get element 0 a i is only ever 0 (the first).

#### Problem 2

You have specified variable **in** as the loop counter, but then used *i* within the loop e.g. you have

```
for (int in = 0; in < help.length; in++) {
    if (help[i].equals("40")) {
        an = R.raw.a40;
        my.add(an);
    } .........
}
```

Either change every occurrence of **i** in the loop to in or change `int in = 0; in < help.length; in++` to `int i = 0; i < help.length; i++`

Comment: @Krümelopment you got it thanks. You can also click the up/down arrows to upvote/downvote (show appproval/dislike). However, downvoting, costs reputation (get upvotes and you gain reputation e.g like you just have).